# Element shifting when updating text attribute

Tags: javascript, text, svg, raphael

Here's what I'm looking at. I have a text element:

```
var label = paper.text(100, 100, "Test String").attr({some attrs});
```

It appears where I want it to and everything is good. The problem comes when I go to update the text attribute later.

```
label.attr({text: "My new label text"});
```

When I do this the text element gets shifted a small amount in the positive y direction, so downward.

When I check the x and y position values before and after the change they are identical. I have no idea what to do. I noticed it not happen once in a friends browser, Chrome, which is the same one I'm using.

Any ideas? I'd rather not have to alter the y value every time I change the text attr.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tested this using other browsers as well? Please provide a fiddle or plunk demonstrating the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is feasible for your project, but you can try combining your raphael elements with standard html elements. Your label could be a div that is positioned and styled with jQuery. If you need to dynamically change the text of the label, you can just use the jQuery `.html()` attribute for the div, which will not change its position. This might not be the most elegant solution, but integrating jquery and raphael works well in most situations and guarantees standardization of text positioning/styling across browsers.